# Can't get my threading to work properly in this simple chat program

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, pyzmq

We are doing a simple chat program in python using the `PyZMQ` library. So that two `clients` can talk to each other via a `server`. But we cant get our threading to work properly.. We need one thread to check the socket for incoming messages, and one that sends messages to the socket. But right now the program simply freezes, and I cant figure out why.

Code here: https://gist.github.com/TheFelixR/1be20e8f510266d152d6947bddf0b31a

Comment: We're breaking all the records, this is the 5th question with this problem today. `target=c.reciever()` -> `target=c.reciever`. Do not __call__ the function when you're trying to pass it as a parameter.

Comment: @Rawing if I do that I get a bunch of errors from the library..